# I get a long beep in my Laptop

Tags: laptop

I have a Hp Laptop.

Sometimes when i switch it on, I get a Long Beep and it gets shutdown,

And if i switch on my Lap after some days, It works Good.

Is the problem in Processor fan or RAM?, If so, How can i fix it?

Comment: Does it get hot? More than normal I mean.

Comment: Yes!!! It gets Hot ..

Comment: By the way, you should try not to use it in the current state. Overheat may damage your laptop "permanently".

Comment: Any other go to avoid over heating

Comment: @yms:ok thanx..

Answer (score 1):

Before you start spending money and effort, check the code corresponding to the beep.

The number and type of beeps are like a morse error code. Follow [these](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bph07107) instructions for identifying and fixing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Bling, I think my problem is 

Continuous beeping without pause--->Serious system related issue such as CPU overheating

What should i do now?

Comment: Tough call. You can find disassembly instructions for laptops online, but having already disassembled an HP laptop myself recently, it's a real pain. I guess it's a financial/motivational decision. How badly do you want to fix this laptop? There's a chance you will spend days taking it apart and trying to fix it, only to find it's broken forever whereupon you'll spend 2 weeks crying yourself to sleep.

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't disassemble myself?? Right??

Comment: Like I said, depends on how much time you have on your hands. Just be willing to accept failure if you try it :)